# How to implement Graph search (DFS) with Object Oriented design

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, graph

I'm not so sure about what's the best approach to model this problem in the object oriented world.

Suppose I have to represent a graph and its nodes in Java and suppose I want to traverse the graph using a depth first search (DFS).

What is the best approach in Software engineering among these two:

- Create a class `Node`, a class `Graph` and a class `GraphsFunctions` where the `GraphsFunctions` class contains the `DFS` method which takes the `Graph` and a `Node` as parameters. Something like this: `public void DFS(Graph g, Node n)` and the call `new GraphsFunctions().DFS(new Graph(), new Node())`
- Create a class `Node` and a class `Graph` where the class `Graph` contains the method `DFS` which only takes a `Node` as a parameter. Something like this: `public void DFS(Node n)` and the call `new Graph().DFS(new Node())`

I would rather use the first of the two options but I can't say why it's the best for me. Can you tell me what makes the best choice, actually the best?

Comment: Do you need to access private instance methods/fields of the `Graph`? It sounds like you need to use the [iterator pattern](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/iterator_pattern.htm).

Comment: So u want this to be extendable so that you can easily add any upcoming graph functionalities without much effort?

Comment: @SupunWijerathne yes, I would like to separate the duty of the classes, so Node class represents nodes of the graph, Graph represents the graph and GraphsFunctions represents function over graphs. I wanted to know if this is stylistically better than simply creating the function inside the Graph class and if it represents a certain pattern.

Comment: @Matt I think according to your requirements and possible extensions, the best way to do it is using command pattern. https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/command

Comment: @Matt: if you are happy with any of the two answers given you might want to consider accepting it. ;)

Comment: @Neuron sure I will, I'm still thinking about it and solving the problem on my project. I'll accept it in the next few days.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This really depends on mostly two things:

1. How much encapsulation you want in your project. More encapsulation is usually better, but it can come at the price of over engineering the problem, which can cause a lot more work which you want to avoid for small projects which wont grow over time.
2. Your own personal style. Each developer will develop his or her own style over time which will be clearly distinguishable from other developers. The most important thing is consistency throughout a project

Assuming you want (only) **good** encapsulation I would personally do it like the following..

Create an interface `GraphSearch` and define your `search(Graph g, Node n)` method in there. Now have a class called `DFSearch` and possibliy `BFSearch`.
If - at some point - a method wants to perform searches on a `Graph` you can specify the search algorithm which should be used.

If you want **great** encapsulation, I would recommend using the [iterator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator_pattern) as `DFS` and `BFS` are basically just iteration orders.

Start by creating an Interface `GraphIterator` instead. It simply extends `Iterator<Node>` which means it can iterate over Nodes in some order.

```
public interface GraphIterator extends Iterator<Node> {

}
```

Create as many implementations of this algorithm as you like. An empty construct for `DFS` looks like this:

```
public class DFSIterator implements GraphIterator {
    private Graph g;

    public DFSIterator(Graph g) {
        this.g = g;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        // todo: implement
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Node next() {
        // todo: implement
        return null;
    }
}
```

Next you can still create your Interface `GraphSearch`..

```
public interface GraphSearch {
    Node search(Graph g, Node n);
}
```

And one simple implementation would be `IterationSearch` which can only perform searches with a given `Iterator`.

```
public class IterationSearch {
    public Node search(Graph g, Node n, GraphIterator iter){
        Node current = null;
        while (iter.hasNext()){
            current = iter.next();
            if (current.equals(n)){
                return n;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

It just iterates over the `Iterator` and compares each element to the searched node. Next create your class `DFSearch` which is the first actual `GraphSearch`...

```
public class DFSearch extends IterationSearch implements GraphSearch{
    @Override
    public Node search(Graph g, Node n) {
        return search(g, n, new DFSIterator(g));
    }
}
```

Now your `Graph` can extend `Itarable<Node>` and return one of your iterators as the default iterator. This way you could nicely iterate over your `Graph`.

```
public class Graph implements Iterable<Node> {
    @Override
    public Iterator<Node> iterator() {
        return new DFSIterator(this);
    }
}
```

and use it like the following:

```
Graph g = createGraph();
for (Node n : g) {
    // do things...
}
```

The great thing about this solution is that you can make the `Iterator`s inner classes of your `Graph`, which allows them to access private members. This often improves performance significantly as you don't have to treat the `Graph` as a [black box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_box).

Comment: For many uses of DFS (detecting cycles, ...), you will want separate callbacks when first encountering a node, and when leaving this node.

Comment: so why not just add listeners to the `GraphIterator` interface?

Comment: You would need two types of listeners - one for start-of-visit, and another one for end-of-visit. The result will be very, very similar to the DfsVisitor interface I proposed.

Answer (score 2):

Best in terms of fast-to-code, easy-to-modify, or some other criterion? Unless you come up with a very precise definition of "what is good", do not expect to find "best".

My first answer would be to use a graph library for Java. Most come with DFS already implemented:

- Already implemented and debugged.
- Good documentation.
- No company will generally want me to reinvent the wheel.

However, since your question is probably part of a do-it-yourself course, I would instead recommend:

- `Node` class, which can provide access to neighbors, and has equals and hashcode methods.
- `Graphs` class, which can build graphs and display them. Includes a `Dfs(Graph g, Node start, DfsVisitor visitor)` method. This would be a utility class with all-static methods, in the same vein as JDK's `Collections` or `Files`.
- `Graph` class, with a list of nodes (and possibly other things, such as the possibility of returning an iterator to a list of edges).
- `DfsVisitor`, an interface for visitors:
- `Main` class, which builds a graph and calls your DFS on the graph with the useful payload in the visitor.

Because DFS *by itself* is useless - it is just a node-visiting strategy. Its value is in what it does *before* and *after* it visits a node. Unless you allow this to be customized, placing a DFS algorithm into `GraphsFunctions` or `Graphs` makes no big difference: it is not likely to be reused outside of whatever payload you have built into it.

```
 public interface DfsVisitor() {
    void started(Graph g, Node node);   // when first encountered
    void finished(Graph g, Node node);  // when all children processed
 }
```